# Define a parameter depending on the hostname

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I my `Gruntfile.js` I need to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
if (hostname == 'host1') : port=9000
else                     : port=9001
```

How can I get `hostname`? (this would be the host where I am running `grunt`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var hostname = require("os").hostname();
```